# Ubuntu 12.04 terminal has no internet proxy server

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, terminal, internet

Okay so my problem is that i got internet in browser but terminal has no internet access.
Maybe i lack of configuration of terminal. I'm using proxy that is auto configure in company network.

Comment: Terminal does not use the internet, it's the command you type in it that does and they have to be configured individually to use the proxy. Most of them don't even support proxies I believe. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: apt-get update dont even work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your Ubuntu settings, and go to Network settings. I'm sure there is a global proxy configuration there. Make sure that it points to your host's IP. 
If it is not, may be you are able to browse Internet as it is explicitly set to use the proxy, that your rest of Ubuntu system may not know.

Answer (score 0):

There is an env var that might help if all else doesnt work.. 
$http_proxy is used to specify url to proxy. refer to this [link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-proxy-environment-variable/)

Answer (score 0):

If you go into the network app (superkey then just type network) click on network proxy then select manual and fill in your proxy setting in all the boxes and click apply system wide this will also apply your setting to the terminal.  If you have the terminal open at the time you will probably have to close it and open a fresh one.